# remove rogue number before doctype

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with a layout view as a standard page. I am then adding in things like menubar and content etc within this layout.

On all but one page there is no problem, however, one page produces a rogue '1' just before the doctype

```
1<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This is not effecting the function but there is a rogue number 1 right under the navbar on this page and I have no idea how to get rid of it. I thought it could be some whitespace after a php function but I have checked the controller and its fine.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Somewhere, something is echoing out the 1

Comment: I have looked everywhere and I can't see a rouge echo statement. If this was the case would I be right in saying that this would have to be an echo in my template view as this gets loaded before the other subviews? But come to think of it it can't be in the template as otherwise it would be on every page

Comment: try: grep -r "1<!DOCTYPE html>” directory-path

Comment: There are more functions than only echo which can output stuff. You might wanna search for calls to functions like print, var_dump, var_export, printf or calls to functions of this kind http://de1.php.net/manual/de/function.flush.php

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
> grep -r "1<!DOCTYPE html>” directory-path
```

or

> grep -r "echo 1” directory-path

or

> grep -r "echo true” directory-path

etc..

Comment: thanks for trying to help but I get `bash: !DOCTYPE: event not found`

Comment: I was gonna update to say look for "echo 1" it could also be an echo true

Comment: I've had this same problem before, not with codeigniter and usually the error is just some erroneous printing and then you find it and are like "oh.."

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will continue the search :(

Comment: Finally!! Found it by accident while commenting out some code